# MVC3 Routing problem HTTP 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm at a loss trying to figure out why I have Actions that are returning 404 'The Resource cannot be found' errors. 
Controller Name: ItemManagementController
My Index view has list of items in a table. Each row contains two links, 'Delete' and 'Request Update'.  The Delete link calls a Delete action and works fine. The Request Update gives me the 404 error, and seems as if trying to navigate to a URL like http://localhost/TVAPDev/ItemManagement/RequestUpdate?itemID=9.

I have to assume I'm missing something simple, as they are identical in what they do from the view aspect. The actions as defined in the controller are both similar except that they call different methods on a service layer, but that's it.

Here are my two Controller Actions.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult Delete(int itemID) {
    var svc = new ItemManagementService(_repository);
    var requestModel = svc.GetItemDeleteModel(itemID);
    svc.DeleteItem(requestModel);
    var message = requestModel.ActionMessage;
    return Json(new { id = itemID, ChangeStatus = requestModel.ItemDetails.ItemChangeStatus.ToString(), ChangeType = requestModel.ItemDetails.ItemChangeType.ToString(), message});
     }


[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult RequestUpdate(int itemID) {
    var svc = new ItemManagementService(_repository);
    var requestModel = svc.GetItemUpdateRequestModel(itemID);
    svc.RequestItemUpdate(requestModel);
    var message = requestModel.ActionMessage;
    return Json(new { id = itemID, ChangeStatus = requestModel.ItemDetails.ItemChangeStatus.ToString(), ChangeType = requestModel.ItemDetails.ItemChangeType.ToString(), message });
    }
```

Here are the links as they are defined in the View

```
<td class="tblist" style="white-space: nowrap;">
    @Html.ActionLink("Request Update", "RequestUpdate", new { itemID = item.ItemID }, new AjaxOptions {
                                   HttpMethod = "POST",
                                   Confirm = "Request an Update to this item?",
                                   OnSuccess = "actionCompleted"
                                   })break;
    }
</td>
<td class="tblist" style="white-space: nowrap;">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { itemID = item.ItemID }, new AjaxOptions {
   HttpMethod = "POST",
   Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this Item?",
   OnSuccess = "actionCompleted"
       })
</td>
```

Again, the Delete here works without issue.  The Request Update link gives me the Http 404 error.

Anyhelp here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I noticed that one of the calls uses Ajax.ActionLink while the other uses Html.ActionLink. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `AjaxOptions` on a normal `Html.ActionLink` (which is what `Request Update` is)?

Maybe you wanted it to be like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Request Update", 
    "RequestUpdate", 
    new { 
        itemID = item.ItemID 
    }, 
    new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        Confirm = "Request an Update to this item?",
        OnSuccess = "actionCompleted"
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing something simple like that, but I just wasn't seeing it.  I have 4 other links that I didn't post as part of this, but they are a mix of HTML links and Ajax links, so that made it a bit more difficult to find.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Check your View code... the delete is using the Ajax html helper and the update is using the regular html helper.